# Laravel 9 Enum model casting not casting to string

Tags: php, laravel, enums

I'm using an Enum on my model's `AppLoanPurpose` field which stores an integer in the database. The integer then corrosponds to something, for example, 0 means "Other" and 1 means "Groceries".

When I cast my field, I'm still seeing the integer value returned rather than my string.

What am I missing?

```php
<?php

namespace App\Enums\Applications\GB\Payday;

enum LoanPurpose: Int
{
    case OTHER = 0;
    case GROCERIES = 1;

    public function label()
    {
        return match($this) {
            self::OTHER => 'Other',
            self::GROCERIES => 'Groceries'
        };
    }
}
```

Model

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\Casts\Json;
use App\Enums\Applications\GB\Payday\LoanPurpose;

class ApplicationGBPayday extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'application_gb_paydays';

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'AppLoanPurpose' => LoanPurpose::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Get the model's application
     */
    public function application()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Application::class, 'modelable');
    }
}
```

Comment: And `AppLoanPurpose` is a column in your database?

Comment: It certainly is. And it's a `TINYINT` column on my `ApplicationGBPayday` model.

Comment: How are you using it?

Comment: `ApplicationGBPayday::find(1);` as a query in the controller.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/site-improvements/get-enum-by-int-reverse

Comment: Ok, but how do I apply this to the cast?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `enum`, you have to treat enum as a regular object.

```
enum LoanPurpose: Int {
    case OTHER = 0;
    case GROCERIES = 1;

    public function label() {
        return match($this) {
            self::OTHER => 'Other',
            self::GROCERIES => 'Groceries'
        };
    }
}

$enum = LoanPurpose::GROCERIES;
```

The above will create an instance of `LoanPurpose` containing two attributes, `name` and `value`.

```
= LoanPurpose {#xxxx
    +name: "GROCERIES",
    +value: 1,
  }
```

Calling those attributes

```
// will output: GROCERIES
$enum->name;
// will output 1
$enum->value;
```

If you add a method to `LoanPurpose`, you still have to call that method in order to do something useful. In your setup, you just have to call the `label` method which performs a `match` with whatever you're matching.

```
// will output: Groceries 
$enum->label();
```

If you do **not** want to call the `name` or `value` of the enum instance, you could use an attribute accessor like `getAppLoanPurposeAttribute` and do just that.

```
use App\Enums\Applications\GB\Payday\LoanPurpose;

class ApplicationGBPayday extends Model {
// ...
  public function getAppLoanPurposeAttribute($value) {
    return return LoanPurpose::from($value)->name;
  }
// ...
```

Just remember that you will have lost any usefulness an enum has to offer because `ApplicationGBPayday::AppLoanPurpose` will never return a `LoanPurpose` instance.

So the following would **not** be possible

```
$ApplicationGBPayday::AppLoanPurpose == LoanPurpose::OTHER
```

As stated in @silver's answer, you can also use the `CastAttribute` interface, or entirely create an instance of `Attribute` and return that instead, which I think would be much easier.

**update**

So reading all the comments you made, the attribute `AppLoanPurpose` for model `ApplicationGBPayday` can be used as follow as specified in the example given in your question.

```
$model = new ApplicationGBPayday([
  'AppLoanPurpose' => 1 // or LoanPurpose::GROCERIES
]);

// will output: 1
$model->AppLoanPurpose->value;
// will output: GROCERIES
$model->AppLoanPurpose->name;
// will output: Groceries
$model->AppLoanPurpose->label();
```

If you're not already using it, I can really advice using `tinker` with [laravel-web-tinker](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-web-tinker) from spatie. It gives you a lot of space to test around.

Answer (score 0):

Casting is converting an attribute value into a supported data type,

You can't just cast an attribute to your own data type, check the supported data type [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

You have to create your own [custom cast](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts) before you can use it, otherwise, just use an [Accessor and Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

**EDIT**
[enum casting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#enum-casting) is supported in PHP 8.1 or above

Comment: Right... so it sounds like I need the inverse? E.g: convvert the value **0** to the string of **Other** using my label method somehow.

Comment: I might have been mistaken as I never tried it, but I think Enum casting is supported in Laravel 9 & PHP 8.1, try removing the label function inside your enum and see if that changes anything

Comment: @RyanH You just have to call the `label()` method, `enum` is just an object, so when you call `$model->AppLoanPurpose`, you need to call the label method `$model->AppLoanPurpose->label()`. I'll try to give a short answer what options there are.

Comment: Yes, but how on my `casts` array? I've just tried: `LoanPurpose::class->label()` on the `AppLoanPurpose` key but this is a syntax error. I don't really want to make lots of new custom attributes just for one.

Comment: I need to retain the integer value for my column, but cast to the `label()` method based on the integer value of the enum.

Comment: @RyanH Im not sure if that would work with casting as it act both as accessor and mutator, your set-up should have been fine and set the integer value in the database column, but you should be getting an enum instace like `LoanPurpose::OTHER` as the attribute output

Comment: If I directly interact with my enum in a controller and pass the value through it works as I'd like. For example: `LoanPurpose::from(4)->label()`, surely this concept could be applied within a cast or a custom case? Not sure how I'd pas the cast instance through to it though.

Comment: just create a custom cast or accessor/mutator if you dont want the enum instance as the output